# Not free as a bimodule.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with 1. I am not following why the ring $R$ is free as a right or left module over itself but not as an $R$-bimodule.

Clearly for any $r \in R$, $r=1r1$, so one is a basis as a bimodule. Shouldn't the ring be non-unital? And in this case, what is an example?

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a ring with unit 1 as you say. By $R$ is "free as a bimodule" it often means $R$ is free as a module over $R\otimes R^{op}$, where $(a\otimes b)*r=arb$ (conventions differ in literature). Recall the definition of a free module is a direct sum of $R$. Thus in general $R$ is not free as an $R$ bimodule. In practice, often one work with the case $R$ being a $k$-algebra like polynomial ring over a field.

This is one of the motivation of [the bar complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_complex), namely to measure to what extent $R$ fails to be a flat $R\otimes R^{op}$ module.